# Sorted PHP Array to New Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting, for-loop

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => -1
            [2] => -1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => B
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => C
            [1] => -1
            [2] => 0
        )

)
```

My objective is to sort this array by each nested array, meaning that I want to sort the array by the values of [1] in each, then by the values of [2] in each, etc. My current code is below, and I can understand why it doesn't provide the result that I want. Each time the loop passes through, it overrides $csvarray and I get just multiples of the same thing.

I want to put each sorted array into its own array so I can display them in an HTML table later. I've tried setting variables using $i but have had no success.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($csvarray); $i++) {
    uasort($csvarray, function($a, $b) {
        return $b[$i] <=> $a[$i];
    });

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($csvarray);
    echo "</pre>"; 

}
```

**User AbraCadaver gave me the correct answer for what I was looking for, with the following:**

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($csvarray); $i++) {
    array_multisort(array_column($csvarray, $i), SORT_DESC,
                    $csvarray, SORT_DESC);


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($csvarray);
    echo "</pre>"; 

}
```

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @u_mulder For this loop I would have an array for each sort that I plan to json encode and run through a web API. The issue is that the CSVs that make up the original array will have variable column amounts, which is why I need the loop in the first place. I'd have an array that's sorted DESC by the values of the nested [1], then an array sorted by nested [2], etc.

Comment: `usort($csv, function ($a, $b) { return $a[0] <=> $b[0] ?: $a[1] <=> $b[1] ...; })` – You need to put the loop (or an `array_reduce`) *inside* the comparison function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just extract those columns, sort them and then sort the original:

```
array_multisort(array_column($csvarray, 1), SORT_DESC,
                array_column($csvarray, 2), SORT_DESC,
                $csvarray, SORT_DESC);
```

If you want `SORT_ASC` (ascending), then you can omit those arguments entirely as that is the default.

For a dynamic number of columns you could try this:

```
foreach($csvarray as $row) {
    array_shift($row);
    $values[] = implode('|', $row);
}
array_multisort($values, $csvarray);
```

Comment: I added this comment to my original post, but the CSVs I upload will have variable amounts of columns based on the analysis. Would this be possible in a loop for $i from 1 to X(however many columns I have in that particular CSV)? I need be able to extract the order of [0] from it at the end.

Comment: But you want to ignore the 0 index?

Comment: This actually worked exactly how I wanted it to! I added the result to my original post. Thanks so much.